# problem having copyright notice and header at the same time in IEEEtrans template

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, ieeetran, ieee-style

I have problem having IEEE copyright notice and Conference header both at the same time in the first page of my paper that uses [IEEE Trans class](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html).

I notice that `\thispagestyle{fancy}` makes the copyright notice disappear! when I comment it, I have copyright notice back but I miss the first page header (header starts from second page).

my code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyhead{}
\chead{12$^{th}$ Iranian Conference on Intelligence Systems, 4-6 February 2014, Bam, Iran}
\fancyfoot{}

\begin{document}
\title{Paper Title Goes Here.}


\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author1}
\IEEEauthorblockA{
Dept. of Math and Computer Science\\
Higher Education Complex of Bam \\
Kerman, Iran \\
E-mail:author1@uk.ac.ir.
}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author2}
\IEEEauthorblockA{
Dept. of Math and Computer Science\\
Shahid Bahonar University\\
Kerman, Iran \\
E-mail: auhtor2@uk.ac.ir}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author3}
\IEEEauthorblockA{
E-mail: author3@gmail.com}
}

%%%%
\IEEEpubid{
  \makebox[\columnwidth][l]
  {\hfill
978-1-4799-1228-5/13/\$31.00~\copyright~2013 IEEE
  }
  \hspace{\columnsep}
  \makebox[\columnwidth]{}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
put your abstract in here...
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
semantic web, Internet, Security
\end{IEEEkeywords}

%%% This line removes the copyright notice!!!
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\section{First}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second}
\lipsum[2-10]
\end{document}
```

output **with** `\thispagestyle{fancy}`. **header:yes copyright:no**
[image]

output **without** `\thispagestyle{fancy}`. **header:no copyright:yes**
[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated. My last paper got published with this bug. no one noticed that! I don't want IEEE to reject publishing my next paper because of this stupid bug.

Comment: Header means? Where it appears?

Comment: @tex Header mean header! simple header goes above the pages. `fancyhdr` package creates header and footer. I used it. let me add the output picture to my post.

Comment: Are you sure conference papers need headers like this. I have send papers without heaqdings, since the IEEE manual says so. From the manual "Conference papers do not have running headings"

Comment: The headers are added by the conference publication office automatically. you only need to use the template `ieeeconf`

Comment: @percusse I am trying to make a template for a conference! I think I'm the only one who use it at last :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the organizers of an IEEE sponsored conference want headers like this for their conference papers, they must have their own way to include them that is compatible with the `IEEEtran` class.  I can't imagine they have suggested using the `fancyhdr` package, which conflicts with `IEEEtran`.  @Werner's solution works but effectively overrides `IEEEtran` headers.

The `conference` option of `IEEEtran` removes running headers from your paper.
This was their choice, I guess, and normally that should be respected --- they're the publishers and they should get what they want (or they should make sure that they implement what they want in the `IEEEtran` class that they provide).

If you have to use the `conferece` option and you absolutely want to have a running header, both in the first page and in all other pages, then I suggest that you get rid of the `fancyhdr` package and that you add something like the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@ps@headings\ps@headings
\let\old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle
\def\confheader#1{%
  % for all pages except the first
  \def\ps@headings{%
    \old@ps@headings%
    \def\@oddhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
    \def\@evenhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
  }%
  % for the first page
  \def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
    \old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle%
    \def\@oddhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
    \def\@evenhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
  }%
  \ps@headings%
}
\makeatother

\confheader{%
  12$^{th}$ Iranian Conference on Intelligence Systems,
  4-6 February 2014, Bam, Iran
}
```

Also, I suggest that you end your lines with `%` in your `\IEEEpubid`, unless you want the copyright notice not to be right-aligned properly with the left column.

```
\IEEEpubid{%
  \makebox[\columnwidth][l]%
  {\hfill%
978-1-4799-1228-5/13/\$31.00~\copyright~2013 IEEE%
  }%
  \hspace{\columnsep}%
  \makebox[\columnwidth]{}%
}
```

Comment: You're right. Getting rid of fancy header is better. and +1 for your note on using `%` at the end of those lines. I still don't get it! `%` is for comment but here it seems to act like a command or something!

Comment: The newline generally counts as a space in the bodies of macros.  If you don't want that, adding a `%` after the last character treats the rest of the line as a comment.  This saves you of that space (and ignores leading spaces on the next line too).

Answer (score 1):

[`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) conflicts with (or overrides, rather) the header/footer setting of the [`IEEEtran` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran). You could, however, add the lines

```
\makeatletter
\fancyfoot[L]{%
  \normalfont\footnotesize%
  \raisebox{\footskip}[1.5ex]{%
    \makebox[\columnwidth][r]{978-1-4799-1228-5/13/\$31.00~\copyright~2013 IEEE}}}
\makeatother
```

to your preamble. This inserts the copyright content in the `[L]`eft footer, raised up into place within the left column. However, you will have to set another page style that excludes this from page 2 onward. So, perhaps page 1 could use `\thispagestyle{fancy}`, while the rest of your document could use `\pagestyle{nocopyright}`, where you

```
\fancypagestyle{nocopyright}{%
  % <header similar to fancy>
  % <footer only page # in centre>
}
```

This *is* something you need to sort out with the journal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it after a couple of hours of trying.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% make room on the footer of the first page for the copyright note
\IEEEpubid{
}

\newcommand{\conftitle}{IEEE International Conference on Yada Yada}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\chead{\conftitle}
\cfoot{\thepage}

% style for the first page only
\fancypagestyle{pageStyleOne}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[C]{\conftitle}
%   \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}    % do you want page number on the first page?
    \fancyfoot[L]{978-x-xxxx-xxxx-x/xx/\$31.00 \copyright2014 IEEE}
}

\makeatletter
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Awesome Paper on Yada Yada}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{pageStyleOne}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{abstract}
    This is the best thing since sliced bread.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
% text text text

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem any different to [my suggestion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134363/5764)...

Comment: Not much originally, apart from my answer being a full example that I had to work out from the answers on this thread and on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165061/header-and-footer-in-ieeetran
Since then, I found it better to move the copyright note from the box within the footer of the left column, to the left footer of the page itself.