# Lyx IEEEtran template copyright overlaps text, authors not appearing

Tags: lyx, pdf, ieeetran, lyx-layouts, ieee-style

How do you make certain that the copyright and publisher id mark are correctly located at the bottom of an IEEEtran template Lyx document when rendered as PDF?

I've tried a couple of suggestions but no matter what it always appears to overlap with the text of the document at the bottom of page 1 (see first image).

Also, although it specifies in the template that your name and paper title will appear next to the name of the journal it doesn't render in the pdf even for the example that comes with a fresh install of Lyx.

How do you get the authors and paper title to appear with the journal title in the upper left corner of the pdf? (see 2nd image).

issue with copyright overlapping and author names as programmed in the Lyx example that do not show in the pdf in the upper left corner with the journal name:

[image: copyright]

[image]

Here's some suggestions I attempted but none worked:

[problem having copyright notice and header at the same time in IEEEtrans template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134360/problem-having-copyright-notice-and-header-at-the-same-time-in-ieeetrans-templat)

http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/     (see publisher ID mark)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? I am experiencing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: See the answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213338/copyright-notice-overlapping-with-text-in-lyx/213346#213346

Answer (score 0):

Find the overlapping paragraph in LyX, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, input `\IEEEpubidadjcol` twice at the beginning and end of this paragraph.

Comment: Why at the beginning and end?