# Copyright notice overlapping with text in Lyx

Tags: formatting, header-footer, lyx, ieeetran, ieee-style

I have a copyright notice on my IEEE Journal that is overlapping with my text while using Lyx and I am not sure why it is happening or what I can do to fix the problem.

I have tried looking up ways to adjust the footer and even have seen this question asked by someone else [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145258/lyx-ieeetran-template-copyright-overlaps-text-authors-not-appearing), but no one has answered.

Here is an image of the problem I am describing:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Find the overlapping paragraph in lyx, use ctrl+L, input "\IEEEpubidadjcol" at the beginning and end of this paragraph.

The question seems to have been resolved here:

[How to avoid overflow using \IEEEpubid on the first column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146227/how-to-avoid-overflow-using-ieeepubid-on-the-first-column)

The trick is to add \IEEEpubidadjcol in sections of text in the Lyx document that form the first column and second column of the papoer.