# Header and footer in IEEEtran

Tags: header-footer, ieeetran

How to do this in IEEEtran `conference` format:

> Add a header on first page of the paper as ,conference name
>   Add a footer on first page of the paper , notice
>   Add a footer on rest of the pages of the paper, SCEECS

Answer (score 8):

In the absence of a MWE, I let loose my imagination ;)

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{SCEES}    %%% change C to L or R as needed
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[C]{Conference on \LaTeX}     %% C or L or R.
  \fancyfoot[L]{This is a notice}%                        %% C or L or R.
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \setlength\unitlength{1in}%
    \hspace*{\dimexpr0.5\paperwidth\relax}%%  change \dimexpr0.5\paperwidth\relax appropriately
    \makebox(0,-0.75)[c]{\Large Conference on \LaTeX}%
}}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \setlength\unitlength{1in}%
    \hspace*{\dimexpr0.5\paperwidth\relax}%%  change \dimexpr0.5\paperwidth\relax appropriately
    \makebox(0,0.75)[c]{\Large Notice}%
}}
% paper title
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}


\author{\authorblockN{Michael Shell}
\authorblockA{School of Electrical and\\Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology\\
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\
Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
\and
\authorblockN{Homer Simpson}
\authorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\
Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\and
\authorblockN{James Kirk\\ and Montgomery Scott}
\authorblockA{Starfleet Academy\\
San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212\\
Fax: (888) 555--1212}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\kant[1]
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\pagestyle{fancy}
\kant[1-40]


\end{document}
```

[image]

**With `lipsum` and `tikz`:*8

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{SCEES}    %%% change C to L or R as needed
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[C]{Conference on \LaTeX}     %% C or L or R.
  \fancyfoot[L]{This is a notice}%                        %% C or L or R.
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
% paper title
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}


\author{\authorblockN{Michael Shell}
\authorblockA{School of Electrical and\\Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology\\
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\
Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
\and
\authorblockN{Homer Simpson}
\authorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\
Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\and
\authorblockN{James Kirk\\ and Montgomery Scott}
\authorblockA{Starfleet Academy\\
San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212\\
Fax: (888) 555--1212}}

\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node at ($(current page.north) + (0,-0.5in)$) {\Large Conference on \LaTeX};
\node at ($(current page.south) + (0,0.65in)$) {\Large Notice};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-40]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I used this code but error is coming like file kantlipsum.sty is not found.

Comment: @user47799 You have to install `kantlipsum` package in your tex distribution. It is just for dummy text. You can use `\usepackage{lipsum}` and `\lipsum[1]` and `\lipsum[1-40]` instead (hoping that you have `lipsum` installed in your computer).

Comment: I have lipsum and I used it, but now error is ABD:everyshipout initializing macros , undefined control sequence.

Comment: undefined control sequence..

Comment: Every shipout initializing macros

Comment: @user47799 It seems you have to have a full up-to-date tex distribution installed! BTW do you have `tikz` installed?

Comment: Yes I have tikz also..